# Correctly deducting a discount from a total price?

Tags: c#, loops, percentage, price

I have this code that takes in a number for a quantity of items. Each item has a base price of $6.00, then there is a discount applied to it based on the  number of items,1-4 items have no discount, 5-9 has a 10% discount, 10-14 get a 14% discount, and 15 or more get a 20% discount. I ran the program but it seems to be outputting the final price without the discount deducted from the total price. What am I doing wrong?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int quantity;
        double price;
        quantity = GetQuantity();
        price = CalculatePrice(quantity);
        WriteLine("Final price for {0} items is {1}.",
          quantity, price.ToString("c"));

    }

    private static int GetQuantity()
    {
        int quantity;
        Write("Enter number of items >> ");
        quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        return quantity;

    }
    private static double CalculatePrice(int quantityOrdered)
    {
        double PRICE_PER_ITEM = 6.00;
        double price = 0;
        double discount = 0;
        int[] quanLimits = { 0, 5, 10, 15 };
        double[] limits = { 0, 0.10, 0.14, 0.20 };
        for (int x = limits.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            if (quantityOrdered >= quanLimits[x])
                discount = limits[x];
        //int x = 0;
        price = quantityOrdered * PRICE_PER_ITEM;
        price = price - (price * discount);
        return price;
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code, what line and where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop with the inner condition is wrong. It iterates through all items and as the given quantity is always >=0 (the last query is the first element in the quanLimits array) the last assignment is discount=0. That's why no discount is calculated.
You can resolve this by reversing the for loop, e.g. start it from index 0.

Comment: Thank you! I am new here and I appreciate the response!

Comment: Welcome! If it helped solving your problem, you can mark it as accepted answer (with the ceck symbol next to it). Happy coding!